# Which version of websockets protocol draft does google chrome implement

Tags: google-chrome, websocket

I am trying to implement a websockets server in java but I am having trouble understanding the version of websocket protocol does google chrome implements. In [this](http://blog.chromium.org/search/label/websockets) blog post the Chromium team mentions that they have implemented version 76 of the websockets protocol which should have the following handshake request (copied from official version 76 spec (section 1.2)):

```
GET /demo HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Key2: 12998 5 Y3 1  .P00
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: sample
Upgrade: WebSocket
Sec-WebSocket-Key1: 4 @1  46546xW%0l 1 5
Origin: http://example.com

^n:ds[4U
```

where as the handshake request I am getting from google chrome(8.0.552.237) is :

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Upgrade: WebSocket
Connection: Upgrade
Host: localhost:8082
Origin: http://localhost:8081
Sec-WebSocket-Key1: g3 I 9w F :  Kt  3?u784C-0 99  5z
Sec-WebSocket-Key2: 4    S5l&Y4m]11+4 032s Ecfl

ïÿÁëƒ^
```

Can somebody please explain me why is there a discrepancy between googles version and the official spec. And what would be the right format of the response for google's version.

PS: does anybody has any estimate by when the websockets protocol would be finalized ?

Comment: here's the [link for official version 76 spec (section 1.2)](http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-hixie-thewebsocketprotocol-76#section-1.2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chrome currently implements [draft-hixie-thewebsocketprotocol-76](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-hixie-thewebsocketprotocol-76) which is also known as [draft-ietf-hybi-thewebsocketprotocol-03](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-hybi-thewebsocketprotocol-03). The protocol and specs are now being published by the IETF HyBi working group thus the 03 numbering is actually more correct and the next versions of the spec will continue that numbering (but most people still call it v76).

The handshake you are getting from Chrome-8.0.552 does match the spec. The differences are because the ordering of the headers can vary and the keys will have different values for every new connection and the host, origin, path, and protocol values depend on how the Javascript invokes the connection and also depend on the URL of the invoking page.

The response will look something like this (although not exactly because the response is generated based on the client handshake):

```
HTTP/1.1 101 WebSocket Protocol Handshake
Upgrade: WebSocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Origin: http://example.com
Sec-WebSocket-Location: ws://example.com/demo
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: sample

8jKS'y:G*Co,Wxa-
```

I've been following the HyBi working group and there is no estimate for when the protocol will be finalized. However, a new draft (04) has already been published trying to address security concerns of the browser vendors. A (05) version will likely be published in the next few weeks. The browser vendors probably won't implement 04 (because there are still significant areas of low consensus). If most of the browser vendors adopt 05 and there are no additional security concerns I suspect that the final version of the protocol will not change much from there.

It's important to note however, that the browser API for WebSockets is likely not going to be affected by changes in the protocol.

Comment: Since thie post was issued, many more revisions were published.  Current version is [draft-ietf-hybi-thewebsocketprotocol-17](http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-hybi-thewebsocketprotocol-17).  Any status on this issue?  What do browsers support as of today?

Comment: A couple of places that track the WebSocket protocol version implemented in browsers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket#Browser_support , https://developer.mozilla.org/en/WebSockets