# Negotiating a WebSocket in C# (Chrome connecting to Unity C# TCP Client)

Tags: c#, javascript, google-chrome, websocket, tcplistener

I've been trying to setup a Unity3D component which negotiates a WebSocket Connection with a Javascript Client.

I have a threaded TCPListener (c#) which handles the HTTP request and attempts to negotiate the Handshake, though it seems to be silently failing. The client closes the connection shortly after I send my response.

I've been following the instructions on this site: http://deusty.blogspot.com/2010/09/websocket-draft-76-algorithm-example.html

Here is the Sockets Log

```
ws://localhost:3000/serverStart

Start Time: Wed Aug 24 2011 23:32:54 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)

t=1314225174926 [st=   0] +REQUEST_ALIVE             [dt=1038]
t=1314225174926 [st=   0]    +SOCKET_STREAM_CONNECT  [dt= 999]
                          --> url = "ws://localhost:3000/serverStart"
t=1314225174927 [st=   1]       +PROXY_SERVICE       [dt=   0]
t=1314225174927 [st=   1]           PROXY_SERVICE_RESOLVED_PROXY_LIST  
                                --> pac_string = "DIRECT"
t=1314225174927 [st=   1]       -PROXY_SERVICE       
t=1314225174927 [st=   1]       +PROXY_SERVICE       [dt=   0]
t=1314225174927 [st=   1]           PROXY_SERVICE_RESOLVED_PROXY_LIST  
                                --> pac_string = "DIRECT"
t=1314225174927 [st=   1]       -PROXY_SERVICE       
t=1314225174927 [st=   1]        HOST_RESOLVER_IMPL  [dt=   2]
                             --> source_dependency = {"id":455371,"type":7}
t=1314225175925 [st= 999]    -SOCKET_STREAM_CONNECT  
t=1314225175926 [st=1000]     WEB_SOCKET_SEND_REQUEST_HEADERS  
                          --> GET /serverStart HTTP/1.1
                              Upgrade: WebSocket
                              Connection: Upgrade
                              Host: localhost:3000
                              Origin: null     
                              Sec-WebSocket-Key1: 52 18  5w7 9       9 2c
                              Sec-WebSocket-Key2: a2PA tG8 1>7242<6(yj7I2

                              \x78\x15\xbc\x75\x2d\x54\x3b\xea
t=1314225175926 [st=1000]     SOCKET_STREAM_SENT     
t=1314225175963 [st=1037]     SOCKET_STREAM_RECEIVED  
t=1314225175963 [st=1037]     WEB_SOCKET_READ_RESPONSE_HEADERS  
                          --> HTTP/1.1 101 WebSocket Protocol Handshake
                              Upgrade: WebSocket
                              Connection: Upgrade
                              Sec-WebSocket-Origin: null
                              Sec-WebSocket-Location: ws://localhost:3000/serverStart
                              Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: webpad

                               \x20\xc3\xc3\xf6\xad\xd2\x76\x63\x48\x86\x0c\xd2\xa6\xb1\x06\x72
t=1314225175963 [st=1037]     SOCKET_STREAM_RECEIVED  
t=1314225175963 [st=1037]     SOCKET_STREAM_RECEIVED  
t=1314225175964 [st=1038] -REQUEST_ALIVE
```

I'm generating the response using the following algo

```
response = MD5( bitpack(
             Key1(numbers only / num of spaces), 
             Key2(numbers only / num of spaces), 
             RequestBody))
```

Any help you can give would be much appreciated?

Comment: the websocket protocol is still evolving and I suspect the example is for an "old(er)" draft... there is a dependency on the browser version too (since different browser versions implement different draft versions)

Comment: I'm fairly certain I have the right version of the spec and I'm dealing with 00 version. Using Chrome 13 (14 will use a new spec once released apparently)

Comment: IF you are dealing with 00 then that is wrong / Chrome 13 implement 03 aka v76 - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878830/which-version-of-websockets-protocol-draft-does-google-chrome-implement/4879388#4879388

Comment: Sorry my fault it appears that the article I mentioned is v76. Still can't seem to find the error.

I've compared it to a valid response and the only thing I can think of is if my Challenge Response is invalid but I'm following the spec

response = MD5(bitpack(
                 Key1(numbers only / num of spaces), 
                 Key2(numbers only / num of spaces), 
                 RequestBody))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opera will (if you enable websockets in opera:config) log the reason for refusing the connection in the error console, which is helpful for debugging where the problem is (if it's the challenge or a typoed header or wrong origin etc).

But I suspect the real problem here is that you're testing from file:/// and Chrome doesn't like that.

Comment: Going to try tonight, if its a permissions bug again this will be the 3rd time I've lost days of dev to Chrome permission bug :'(

Answer (score 0):

I discussed this with some people on the #WhatWG channel on Freenode (so I can't take the credit) and we were wondering why the origin is null. Maybe Chrome has a security implementation in place that disallows connections from null origins (e.g. using file:///).

A suggestion was made to try Opera 11.00 or higher to see if Chrome has a bug here or some security model that disallows this.